# Fortify scan for python project

Tags: python, fortify

Hot to generate Fortify for file for python files.

A similar question is [Fortify, how to start analysis through command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777391/fortify-how-to-start-analysis-through-command#) but it lists the steps for java.

To generate reports for python project, --python-path has to be used.
I tried following steps, but did not work.

Step 1: Clean,build

```
sourceanalyzer -64 -Xms1024M -Xmx10000M -b -verbose -Dcom.fortify.sca.ProjectRoot=/local/proj/9999/ -Dcom.fortify.WorkingDirectory=/local/proj/9999/working -logfile  /local/proj/working/9999/working/sca.log  -clean
```

Step 2: Scan: This step should generate fpr file

```
sourceanalyzer -b 9999 -verbose -Xms1024M -Xmx10000M -Dcom.fortify.sca.ProjectRoot=/local/proj/9999/ -Dcom.fortify.WorkingDirectory=/local/proj/9999/working  -logfile /local/proj/9999/sca.log -python-path /path/to/python -f projec_999.fpr /local/proj/**/*.py
```

This did not generate any fpr file.
The second step gives the warning as:

```
[warning]: The -f option has no effect without the -scan option
[warning]: You may need to add some arguments to the -python-path argument to SCA.
```

I am not sure if I am using the correct command.

1. How to make sure that all python files are being scanned in the directory and subdirectories?
2. Is there any option to add multiple python paths?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step you did only does `Clean`, not the build step.

To perform the translation step for Python you need to specify the directories for the any Python references (`-python-path`) as well as the files to translate.

I am also not sure what you are doing with the ProjectRoot and WorkingDirectory, you know these are used to store temp data/intermediate files for sourceanalyzer and not the location of your source code, correct?

Something like

```
sourceanalyzer -b <buildId> -python-path <directories> <files to scan>'
```

- `<buildId>` can be used to group different projects, you are somewhat doing this yourself when you do the `ProjectRoot` and `WorkingDirectory`  (I am not sure if you need them both, can't remember and I no longer have access to test it out)
- `<directories>` - this is where you can list out the directories that would normally be in your PythonPath environment variable (you might be able to actually call it here and save a lot of hassle).  This is a comma-seperated list for Windows and a colon-seperated list for Linux
- `<files to scan>` this is where you specify the files you want to translate/scan.  You can specify individual files or use wildcard characters (`*` and `**/*` [recursive])

A sample command would look like:

```
sourceanalyzer -b MyApp -python-path %PYTHONPATH% ./MyApp/**/*
```

The other options you are putting in can be used and it would look something like this:

```
sourceanalyzer -b MyApp -Xms1024M -Xmx10G -logfile  /local/proj/working/9999/working/sca.log -python-path %PYTHONPATH% ./MyApp/**/*
```

It is at this step you would check to see what files we translated from your program:

```
sourceanalyzer -b MyApp -show-files
```

Then you would perform the scan command

```
sourceanalyzer -b MyApp -logfile  /local/proj/working/9999/working/sca.log -scan -f project.fpr
```

Answer (score 0):

You may apply `-python-path` multiple times. This solves the problem which separator to use. The list of needed directories may be obtained with python:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```